# Does an example of a function exist where the Lebesgue Integral doesn't work?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I am studying the Lebesgue Integral as part of a project and I am convinced the Lebesgue Integral is a more powerful method of integration than that of Bernhard Riemann's method. An example of where this is established to be true is the Dirichlet Function.

However I am wondering if there is an example of a function where the Lebesgue Integral also struggles to define an accurate area under a function?

**QUESTION EDITED - 00:22 - 04/04/19**

Comment: There is not, since the Lebesgue integral generalizes and *extends* that of Riemann's

Comment: If you are asking for an example of  a function that is neither Riemann integrable nor Lebesgue integrable there are plenty of them,. Even non-measurable functions exist.

Comment: That is what I am asking. What is an example please?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ for all real numbers $x$.

Comment: Is this because the set of reals is uncountable?

Comment: Are you wondering if there are functions that are not Lebesgue integrable but Riemann integrable, or are you unsure if there are any functions that are not Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Any functions that have pre-images of subsets of the range as non-measurable sets should work.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$ is not Lebesgue integrable - an example from wiki entry of [Henstock-Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots and lots of non Lebesgue integrable functions. Here are two examples:

Let $A$ be a non measurable set then the characteristic function of $A$ is not Lebesgue integrable.

For a more wild example define $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ as follows:
If after some term every second number in the decimal expansion of $x$ is recurring (for exampe $0.375389192919593...$) then $f(x)=0.$(the numbers between the recurring digits.) in our case $f(0.375389192919593...)=0.12153....$
If there is no recurrence set $f(x)=0$